# Full List Of Location Attribute For CommandUIDefinition

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, custom-action

I want to display a custom action button on the list view only (not on the DisplayForm).

In the example below the Location attribute for the CommandUIDefinition is set to

> Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children

```
<CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition **Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Display.Manage.Controls._children"**>
      <Button Id="{E22A6CA6-06F0-40E2-B995-34294CAC7422}"
      Command="{2461C3B4-303B-4A19-9610-DD87ECFF7095}"
      Image32by32="~site/_layouts/Images/MYSOLUTION/myimage32.png"
      Image16by16="~site/_layouts/Images/MYSOLUTION/myimage16.png"
      Sequence="0"
      LabelText="Create Child Item"
      Description="Create Child Item"
      TemplateAlias="o1"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
```

But there is also a Location attribute in the CustomAction definition too.

In my example this Location attribute in the CustomAction attribute is set to:

> CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
Id="{F448A055-B646-455E-94AB-64C7A9122789}"
RegistrationType="ContentType"
RegistrationId="0x0100B7080A7BAA48E54694292941D7204275"
**Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"**
Rights="ViewListItems">
<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Define the (UI) button to be used for this custom action -->
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
```

Both Location attributes seem to target different locations even though they are specifying the same custom action location.

[EDIT]

In my example I am adding screenshot as suggested to show the locations:

[image: This Shows The Custom Action button and tab on the List View]

and then the same action also appears on the DisplayForm as in the screenshot below:

[image: This shows the Custom Action button also on the DisplayForm tab even though I do not want it to appear there.]
Is there a full list of these locations for the CommandUIDefinition Location attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Take a look at the contents of this - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.xml. You'll find all the locations.

Answer (score 3):

It is a two step process. The `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"` of `CustomAction` specifies that a button will be added to Display form. And `Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">` of `CommandUIDefinition` specifies that it will be added to the Manage tab of the Display form. Full Example:

```
<CustomAction
    Id="ExportVersionHistory.DisplayForm"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    RegistrationId="0x01"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"
    Rights="ViewVersions">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                 Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
                    <Button
                     Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls.ExportVersionHistory"
                     Alt="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."
                     LabelText="Export Version History"
                     Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png"
                     Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_32.gif"
                     Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                     Sequence="99"
                     TemplateAlias="o1"
                     ToolTipTitle="Export Version History"
                     ToolTipDescription="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."/>
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler
                 Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                 CommandAction="~site/_layouts/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}"
                 EnabledScript="javascript:ExportVersionHistoryDisplayFormEnable();"/>
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
```

See this for more information about Custom Action Locations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**UPDATE**

Based on your update, it appears you want to add a new tab only in ListView. Set `CustomAction` Location to `CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView` and in `CommandUIDefinition` set `Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children"`
See these articles on how to create a tab in ribbon:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2009/12/07/sharepointfoundationhowtoaddtabtoribbon.aspx

Comment: So how can I add it only to the list view and not to both the display form & list view?

Comment: For List view the Custom Action will have `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"` and for `CommandUIDefinition` it may be similar to this  `Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.Controls._children">`

Comment: But I don't want the button to appear on the list item. I need a way for it only to appear on the list view.

Comment: I am not able to get you. Can you add a screenshot in the question showing where you want the button in the ribbon?

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshots.  I tried Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.Controls._children" but it does not work.  Currently the custom action tab appears in both the List View and DisplayForm when it should only appear in the List View.